# Linux Makefile.am error "undefined reference to"

Tags: c, linux, makefile

When I try t compile my program I have this error

```
undefined reference to `printfHello'
```

I make a simple program, with three files hello.c, hello1.c and hello.h

hello1.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
void printfHello() {
    printf("Hello");
}
```

hello1.h

```
void printfHello();
```

hello.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include "hello1.h"   

int main() {
    int errn=0;
    printfHello();
    return errn;
}
```

And I have a Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = client_ev

AM_CPPFLAGS = \
    -I$(top_srcdir)/include \
    -I$(top_builddir)/include
#   $(some_CFLAGS)

EXTRA_DIST = \
    autogen.sh

MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = \
    configure \
    aclocal.m4 \
    Makefile.in

client_ev_SOURCES = hello.c hello1.c
```

If I do ---> cc hello.c -o hello.c hello1.c . It works fine.

I need to define something else in the makefile.am file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the function printfHello() in any of the file. Please first define that function first like

```
void printfHello()
{
 printf("Hello\n");
}
```

Comment: Or else i think you typed the function name wrong in hello1.c file

Comment: I typed the name wrongly, I changed it , but It still doesn't work

Comment: Why haven't u added hello.c and hello1.c in the following line in Makefile.am?
client_ev_SOURCES = client_ev.c hola.c hello.c hello1.c

Answer (score 0):

In file hello1.c change the function PrintHola to printHello. The compiler gives errors because it cannot find the body of printHello when it has a prototype.